# Punctuation rules for informal writing

Tags: syntactic-analysis, punctuation, formality, informal-writing

I have to write something quite informal while being AND staying in a formal context. For this sake I used a lot of punctuation marks without being certain I did this the right way. Is the following snippet correct?

> Forgive me, I didn’t get the chance to take a look at that book of yours (you can blame school for this one – I know ‘lol’, life sucks being an adolescent).

I know this sounds weird but whatever, how would you guys formulate that?

Comment: I'd just drop the *I know 'lol'*

Comment: That confused me. I couldn't work out what it meant. I left it in only because I assumed it was some sort of "in joke" with the recipient.

Comment: "I assumed it was some sort of 'in joke'" - xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frankly, I did find all the punctuation marks a distraction. It's not that they're a problem, but what purpose do they serve? I'd simplify with something like:

> Forgive me, I didn’t get the chance to look at that book of yours. You
>   can blame school for this one, I know, ‘lol’. Life sucks being an
>   adolescent!